# Can't stop the form from submiting despite having JS validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

When clicking submit button the form goes to the action page"formsubmit.html" without filling nothing...

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" action="formsubmit.html" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

JAVASCRIPT (Jquery):

```
$(function () {

function validateForm() {
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (name == null || name == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    if (email == null || email == "") {
        alert("email required");
        return false;
    }
    var phone = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
    if (phone == null || phone == "") {
        alert("please enter a valid phone number");
        return false;
    }
    var subject = document.forms["myForm"]["subject"].value;
    if (subject == null || subject == "") {
        alert("You forgot your message!");
        return false;

      }
   }
});
```

Comment: You need to move the `validateForm()` function *outside* of the jQuery block as you're using an `on*` event handler. If you check the console you'll probably have an error saying your function is not defined as it's out of scope. Better still, get rid of the outdated `on*` attribute and bind your events using unobtrusive JS code.

Comment: Thank you KAD and Rory, that was the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is within an unnamed function closure, it shall be defined globally:

```
// global scope

function validateForm() {
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (name == null || name == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    if (email == null || email == "") {
        alert("email required");
        return false;
    }
    var phone = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
    if (phone == null || phone == "") {
        alert("please enter a valid phone number");
        return false;
    }
    var subject = document.forms["myForm"]["subject"].value;
    if (subject == null || subject == "") {
        alert("You forgot your message!");
        return false;

      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you KAD and Rory, that was the solution

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the `validateForm()` function *outside* of the jQuery block as you're using an `on*` event handler. If you check the console you'll probably have an error saying your function is not defined as it's out of scope. Try this:

```
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (name == null || name == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    if (email == null || email == "") {
        alert("email required");
        return false;
    }
    var phone = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
    if (phone == null || phone == "") {
        alert("please enter a valid phone number");
        return false;
    }
    var subject = document.forms["myForm"]["subject"].value;
    if (subject == null || subject == "") {
        alert("You forgot your message!");
        return false;
    }
}

$(function () {
    // jQuery code here..
});
```

Better still, get rid of the outdated `on*` attribute and bind your events using unobtrusive JS code.

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="formsubmit.html" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
        var name = $('#fname').val().trim();
        if (name == null || name == "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Name must be filled out");
        }

        var email = $('#email').val().trim();
        if (email == null || email == "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("email required");
        }

        var phone = $('#phone').val().trim();
        if (phone == null || phone == "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("please enter a valid phone number");
        }

        var subject = $('#subject').val().trim();
        if (subject == null || subject == "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("You forgot your message!");
        }
    }
});
```